# iTunes Installation on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: playonlinux, itunes

Good day,

I would like to connect my iPad onto my ubuntu 16.04 LTS to transfer files over to my iPad, I have tried on playonlinux but the message I get says I can't sync my iDevice to Ubuntu, how can I connect my iDevice on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

I need to do this, because I'm using my iPad for company purposes? I don't use Windows at all anymore, so there is no way for me to go back either.

I don't want to do virtual machine so please help me sort this out.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/477313/itunes-replacement, https://askubuntu.com/questions/452743/installing-itunes

Comment: related: http://www.libimobiledevice.org/

Answer (score 1):

Install iTunes on Ubuntu
Open the command terminal and type `sudo apt-get install wine` and press “Enter.” Wine installs to Ubuntu, allowing you to download applications not supported by the Linux distribution.

Type `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras` in the command terminal to allow you to manage mp3 and AAC files with Ubuntu.

Go online to apple.com/itunes/download and click “Download Now” to download the 32-bit Windows version of iTunes.

Type `chmod +x iTunesSetup.exe` in the command terminal to make the iTunes installer executable.

Right-click the iTunes installer file downloaded to your computer and select “Open with Wine Windows Program Loader.” ITunes installs to Ubuntu using Wine.

Sync iPad With iTunes on Ubuntu
Launch iTunes by opening the Applications folder and double-clicking “iTunes.” Wine starts and runs iTunes.

Click “iTunes Store” in the left sidebar, click “Sign In” in the top right, type your Apple ID and password in the corresponding text fields, and click “Sign In.”

Connect your iPad to your Ubuntu computer using the device’s USB connector cable. An iPad icon appears in the left sidebar.

Click the iPad icon in the left sidebar and click “Sync” in the bottom right. Sync options are configured through the control panels accessed by clicking the menu items along the top of the iTunes application window.

http://smallbusiness.chron.com/sync-ipad-ubuntu-34326.html

Comment: It should be noted that [winehq](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1347) rates the newer version of itunes compatibility as "garbage"

Comment: @CharlesGreen However, 12.x has silver rating again.

Comment: @Melebius Time marches on, itunes changes and so does wine.  Over the last 13 months it may be that compatability has been restored, but that may only last until the next itunes update.